# query function in cake php

Tags: mysql, cakephp, syntax

I am writing code in php to basically 'map' data from a mySQL database to another database. I am using the code as follows:

```
$results = $this->query("select PT_FS_DATA_ID from PATIENT_FLOWSHEET_DATA where 
    DT_LAST_UPDATED_TIME = (select top 1 DT_LAST_UPDATED_TIME from PATIENT_FLOWSHEET_DATA 
    order by DT_LAST_UPDATED TIME desc) group by PT_FS_DATA_ID;");
```

however, I am getting an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION
```

Everywhere I look this seems to be the correct syntax. Is there something I'm missing here?
I tried putting the controller in there as well `$this->controllerName->query`, but that didn't work either.

Full Code:

```
class CaExtraFlowsheetFields extends CaBase {
public $name = 'CaExtraFlowsheetFields';

/*
NOTE: This is to take all the fields in flowsheet and
maps their id's.
*/
//public $useTable = 'ANSWER_ENTRY';
public $useTable = 'PATIENT_FLOWSHEET_DATA';
public $primaryKey = 'PT_FS_DATA_ID';

protected function getPrimaryKeyValue(
    $hospital_id,
    $patient_id,
    $admission_id = null
) {

return $patient_id;
}

//*CHANGE BEGIN*
$results = $this->query("select PT_FS_DATA_ID from PATIENT_FLOWSHEET_DATA where 
DT_LAST_UPDATED_TIME = (select top 1 DT_LAST_UPDATED_TIME from PATIENT_FLOWSHEET_DATA 
order by DT_LAST_UPDATED TIME desc) group by PT_FS_DATA_ID;");

protected $filedMethodMappings = array(

    'Method_GO' => array(
        CaBase::KEY_MAPPING_LOGIC_COMPLEXITY => CaBase::LEVEL2_COMPLEXITY,
        CaBase::KEY_FIELD_LOGIC_NAME         => 'wsMethod_GO',
);

//########################################################################//
//Note[]>Block[]               //
//>Method that calls LookUpField for every field in flowsheet //                                       //
//########################################################################//
public function wsMethod_GO ($params) {
    foreach($results as $value){

        $questionName = ''.$value;
        $msg_prefix = $this->name . "::" . __FUNCTION__ . ": ". "arrivez-vouz" ;
        $ret = $this->wsLookUpField($params,$questionName,$msg_prefix);
        return $ret;   
    } 
    unset($value);
}
//########################################################################//

public function wsLookUpField($params,$questionName,$msg_prefix){

$arrayValues=array();
    try{    
        $hospital_id  = $params[Constants::KEY_HOSPITAL_ID];
        $patient_id   = $params[Constants::KEY_PATIENT_ID];
        $admission_id = $params[Constants::KEY_ADMISSION_ID];

        $msg_prefix = $this->name . "::" . __FUNCTION__ . ": ". "attendez-vouz: l'hopital= ".$hospital_id.
        " patient= ".$patient_id." admission= ".$admission_id;

        //shows info about given question name
        $msg_prefix = "*!*!*!*Show me ---> ".$questionName." : ".$answer_entry_id.
        " = aic: " .$answer_id_check;

        $ret = array();

        //now with needed fields, grab the A_NAME:
            $params = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                $this->name . '.PID'                => $patient_id,
                $this->name . '.PT_FS_DATA_ID'      => $questionName,           
            ),
            'order' => array(
                $this->name . '.' . $this->primaryKey . ' DESC'
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                $this->name . '.FS_VALUE_TEXT',
            )
        );

    $rs = $this->find('first', $params);

   /* check to make sure $rs has received an answer from the query
      and check to make sure this answer is a part of the most recent
      database entries for this note */
    if (false != $rs) {
            try {                   
                $msg = $msg_prefix . "Data obtained successfully."."<br>".$result;
            $result = $rs;
            $ret = WsResponse::getResponse_Success($msg, $result);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $msg = $msg_prefix . "Exception occurred.";
            $ret = WsResponse::getResponse_Error($msg);
        }
    /*answer was not part of most recent database entries, meaning no
      answer was given for this particular question the last time this
      particular note was filled out. Message is given accordingly.*/
    } else {
        $msg = $msg_prefix . "/No answer given.";
            $ret = WsResponse::getResponse_Error($msg);
        }


    } catch (Exception $e) {
                $msg = $msg_prefix . "Exception occurred.";
                $ret = WsResponse::getResponse_Error($msg);
        }        
return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Are you on the model when performing the query? Also, look at the line number that the error is referencing.

Comment: The line number is $results = $this->query("select PT_FS_DATA_ID from PATIENT_FLOWSHEET_DATA where, and yes I am in the model when I perform the query

Comment: Can you show more code? This is indeed valid code, so I feel like we're missing something from somewhere else.

Comment: I can, it just may be a bit confusing because the class calls/extends a few other classes. I'll edit the original question

Comment: Yep, see the answer posted below. See, posting extra code helps :)

Comment: Hey, Jeremy... you did the research, but I earned the credits... not very fair, I agree. At least, this part of Nath's problem was solved...

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you are doing:

```
class ABC {

    $result = 'whatever';

}
```

You can't declare a variable there!

---

Code needs to be inside a method/function...

```
class ABC
{
    public function wsMethod_GO ($params)
    {
        $result = 'whatever';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little more? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Oh! I didn't even think about that. I've been stuck on this for the last few days. Thanks!! But now I'm getting unexpected T_PUBLIC. Do I need to declare something private in order for this to work?